# Не работает свойство Position у MediaElement

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, media

Я очень надеюсь, что кто-нибудь сможет помочь с решением данной проблемы.
Проект Xamarin Forms (4.8).
На одной из страниц использую mediaElement (не из библиотеки toolkit, а обычную, т.к. версия xamarin не позволяет, а обновить нет возможности по другим причинам).
Разметка XAML:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="hitTrailer"
                                      ShowsPlaybackControls="False"
                                      IsLooping="True"
                                      Scale="1.4"
                                      Aspect="AspectFill"
                                      AutoPlay="True"
                                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                      Source="https://fs.kinomania.ru/media/video/f/20/f2099e4d302ec84b207c3139ef854819.1080.mp4"
                                  >
```

Теперь, если я попытаюсь, например, по событию MediaOpened установить позицию видео на 20 секунд, видео всё равно начинается с 0 секунды. Перепробовал множество вариаций, ничего не помогло.

```
private void HitTrailer_MediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hitTrailer.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
    }
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Свойство `CanSeek`, если оно отдает `False`, то указанный `Source` не поддерживает перемотку.

Comment: В том то и дело, что CanSeek отдает True (проверял)